# cannot serialize interface object to json using jakson

Tags: java, json, spring, web, serialization

Im trying to convert a java object to a json according to an API's declared pattern, using jakson.
but I couldnt figure it out.
how should I do that?

Here are my classes

*ProcessValueBaseDto*

```
package com.ir.tsn;
public class ProcessValueBaseDto implements Serializable {

private String id;
private ProcessValue value;

}
//methods Ommited
```

*ProcessValue*

```
package com.ir.tsn;
public interface ProcessValue<T> extends Serializable {

void setValues(T values);

}
//methods Ommited
```

*ProcessValueDto*

```
package com.ir.tsn;
public class ProcessValueDto implements 
ProcessValue<List<String>> {

private List<String> values;

}
//methods Ommited
```

***the excpected json should be like this***

```
{
   "id": "id1",
   "value": {
          "com.alz.ProcessValueDto": {
            "values": [
              "500000000"
            ]
          }
   }
}
```

***com.alz.ProcessValueDto*** is the name of one of the **ProcessValue.class** implementations in API

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand the question, but the one problem I see from the code you posted is that you have two classes with the same name. Also if the code is all in the same file you should split it up as you can't have more than one public class or interface in the same file.

Comment: sorry thats my bad in explaining classes. I corrected that. but that wasnt a problem in code.

Comment: we still need more info, do you get an error? bad json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the given below class for given JSON.

```
public class MyValue
{
    public List<string> values { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public MyValue MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry for my bad explanation. I edited the question to clear the problem.